# bool vs void vs print or std::cout

Tags: c++

What is the difference between having a void or a bool and why is the answer not displaying right? The more I look up and try to understand the deeper I dig myself into a whole. (eg: std::boolalpha)?!?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>


bool findPair(int* arr, int arrLength, int k)
{
for(int i=0; i<arrLength; i++)
    {   
    for(int j = i+1;j<arrLength; j++)
    {
        if(arr[i] + arr[j] == k)
        {
        printf("Pair Found (%d, %d)", arr[i], arr[j], "\n");
       //return; 
        }
    }
    }
    printf("Pair NOT Found!");
    //return false;
}


int main()
{
    int array[5] = {4,5,1,7,2};
    int sum = 221;
    int arrLength = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);


    findPair(array, arrLength, sum);

    
    std::cout << std::endl << findPair() << std::endl;

   // return 0;


}
```

Gives the following output when a pair is found (int sum = 3;):

```
Pair Found (1, 2)Pair NOT Found!
1
```

And this output when the pair is not found (int sum = 221;):

```
Pair NOT Found!
1
```

Comment: Consider [fixing the warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/arnr9hh4E) in your code before reasoning about its runtime behavior.  They are mistakes!  Do you have a question about how to fix these warnings?

Comment: Your function does not return anything, you commented out the `return`s. You are also ignoring the return value of the function in `main`. `std::cout << std::endl << findPair << std::endl;` prints `1` because the address of the function `findPair` is not `NULL`.

Comment: You don't **call** your function in `std::cout << std::endl << findPair << std::endl;`, you try to output it as if it was a variable. I think compiler tries to convert the pointer on your function into a boolean

Comment: if it's a `void findPair` returns are accepted and code works but if it's a `bool findPair`  I get this error: `return-statement with no value, in function returning 'bool' [-fpermissive]` that's why ignored them

Comment: The fix would have been to say `return true;` instead of `return;` in the case that you've found the pair.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but there's no need to compute `arrLength`; the array is defined to  have 5 elements. If you want a named value for that, use a constant: `const int arrLength = 5; int array[arrLength] = whatever`.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, you've told the compiler that `findPair` returns a `bool`, but the method doesn't actually return `true` or `false`. You've lied to the compiler, and the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants in this case.  A function with a return type should always have a `return` statement that tells the compiler what value to return to the caller (or throw an exception).

A method with a `void` return type does not have to have a `return;` statement, and it's `return;` statements do not have to return a value, but you can still use `return;` statements to tell the computer to stop executing the method and return to the caller.

---

In your case, since you've eliminated the `return` statement after `"Pair Found (%d, %d)"`, the method keeps executing, until it reaches the end of the loop, which is why you see both `printf` statements execute.  Make sure to put a return type there.

Separately, `std::cout << findPair` will try print the address of the function, but since there's no overload for that, it will convert the pointer to a boolean, thus printing `1`.  What you probably wanted was to store the returned value into a `bool` variable, and send *that* to `cout`?

If you want to output `true` or `false` instead of `1` or `0` for `bool` types, then stream out `std::boolalpha` first, as in `std::cout << std::boolalpha << myBoolean;`

Comment: I believe `std::cout << function` will print a `bool`.  The output seems to also reflect that.

Comment: @DrewDormann, there's no difference between `std::cout << function` and `std::cout << &function`.

Comment: You can add that [std::boolalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) is used to display "true" or "false" instead of "1" or "0"; `std::cout << std::boolalpha << findPair(array, arrLength, sum)`